# Somebody is damaging my bike at work (two days in a row) - but I don't know who

Tags: company

For two days in a row, yesterday and today at around 4PM I returned to my bike at the company I work and found screws pushed into my saddle. It's a saddle filled with gel and has a big hole in it now.

**What steps can I take to put a halt to this situation?**

Comment: Why is this a workplace problem? If someone is deliberately damaging your property, inform the police. And park somewhere else.

Comment: I'd make a police report on it. Are you certain no random stranger could come to the bike rack? Even if it is "hidden?" Though it seems strange they would put a screw into the bike seat rather than take the bike seat or put it into a tire to flatten it if their intentions were malicious.

Comment: Or by jumping the fence. Go to the police and... that's it.

Comment: Thank you for your input. Appreciate it. I just find it extremely weird, why would an adult (I guess) do this?

Comment: Those look like sheet metal screws.  Is there any chance that the screws came from inside the seat and worked their way out? Maybe it wasn't a malicious event?

Comment: 2 sheet metal screws in 2 days with no precedent? (I could maybe see the first working loose and coming out but definitely not the second)? OP did anything change on that day?

Comment: Are you really, really, REALLY sure that it's not a random stranger? A friend of mine used to keep his bike in exactly the same circumstances - secure parking lot, fences, security gates, cameras, keycards, guards - strangers still managed to get in and steal his bike twice (they knew it was strangers, not coworkers, due to security cameras, but never caught them).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> What should I do?

You should file a report with the police.

Also, talk to your company's security.  Give them as much information as possible, there may be cameras in the area or some sort of access control that could identify who is doing this.  If there is any evidence to be had, share it with the police to go along with the report.

Comment: Even if there are no cameras covering the area now, security may choose to point one that way.

Comment: And what exactly would you expect the police to do ?

Comment: Talking to a security guard makes sense. Informing the police seems pointless. Even if the whole bike was stolen, they would write it in their statistics but not really be able to do anything. This would count as annoying a police officer with trivialities.

Comment: @quarague this highly depends on the laws of the land. Also destroying another's property IS illegal so a police report would be valid, no matter what they do with it.

Comment: @Hilmar, few things: 1st it is illegal to vandalize somebody's property (there could be lower $ limits on when it is punishable offense though) so if somebody would get caught doing it they might be at least "inconvenienced". 2nd if there is an increase/quite high number of reports in the area police might dedicate more resources to it.

Comment: @quarague OP property was vandalized, thus it should be reported to the police. Does it mean that they will catch the perp? Likely not. But the only way for them to have a chance to do anything about it is to report the act in the first place. If you don't, then don't complain that this stuff keeps happening to you, and others.

Answer (score 9):

Solid answer already and probably appropriate in some areas to go straight to the police.

Others it's best to approach your manager and then security first and see if it can be either dealt with internally or at least firm evidence of the culprit found either by camera footage of people going to that area or installing a camera there or something else.

Getting the police involved without having evidence would act as a deterrent but be unlikely to get the culprit punished or any recompense for your bike seat. And I know I'd be more interested in getting the person than saving other peoples bike seats.

Comment: Also in some places when you call the cops it's hard to stop them putting any small removable objects they come across into their pockets by accident.

Comment: @Wishit, Who would have the motive to do such a thing? Is the bike rack full? Do you use more than one space? It's difficult to figure out the motive of such an idiot, but maybe start there first.

Comment: Is it a new & expensive bike? Is the motive envy?

Comment: The more you think of it the nastier it seems, it's insane, and targeted in some way. Which is why I advised trying to find the chap/chappess/chapit, rather than get the police which would either mean nothing more happens (great) or something worse happens